# Add a term to an attachment submitted from front end

Tags: taxonomy, attachments, terms

I have a front end post form where users can upload a file with their post that I save as an attachment using `media_handle_sideload()`. I need a way to add a term to that attachment so I can show a loop of all specific attachments by a user with that term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`media handle sideload` returns an attachment ID, and attachments are normal posts with the post type 'attachment'. All the same things apply, featured images parents taxonomies post meta etc albeit with a few attachment oriented functions like `wp_get_attachment_image`

So use `wp_set_object_terms` as you normally would, e.g.:

```
$id = media_handle_sideload(.... 
if(!is_wp_error($id)){
    wp_set_object_terms( $id, array(terms...), $taxonomy, $append );
}
```